# dynamoDb put item not populating all params

Tags: go, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have 2 lambdas that do the exact same thing, however, they are both written using different langages.

1st lambda - runs on a node.js environment, when I create my arguments to putItem, as follows:

```
const args = {
          id: "my id",
          __typename: "a type name",
          _version: 1,
          _lastChangedAt: now.toISOString(),
          createdAt: now.toISOString(),
          updatedAt: fields.LastModifiedDate
        }
var recParams = {
        TableName: dynamoTable,
        Key: {
        "id": Id
        },
        Item: args,
        ReturnValues: "ALL_OLD"
      };
```

and then I use the docClient to insert the row. Everything works fine, all the properties are populated in my dynamo row.

I have the exact same written in Golang:

```
    item := RecentItem{
                Id:             "some Id",
                _version:       1,
                __typename: "a type name",
                _lastChangedAt: currentTime.UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700"),
                createdAt:      currentTime.UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700"),
                updatedAt:      currentTime.UTC().Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700"),
            }
av, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(item)
input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
        Item:      av,
        TableName: aws.String(tableName),
    }
```

Everything ALMOST works, the item is inserted, but I am missing all the properties except for the id.

Structure declaration :

```
type RecentItem struct {
    Id             string `json:"id"`
    _version       int    `json:"_version"`
    _lastChangedAt string `json:"_lastChangedAt"`
    createdAt      string `json:"createdAt"`
    updatedAt      string `json:"updatedAt"`
}
```

Not sure why in Go my dynamoDb row is missing properties. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Properties other than **Id** must be exported, i.e, started with an Upper case:

```golang
type RecentItem struct {
    ID             string `dynamodbav:"id"`
    Version        int    `dynamodbav:"_version"`
    LastChangedAt  string `dynamodbav:"_lastChangedAt"`
    CreatedAt      string `dynamodbav:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt      string `dynamodbav:"updatedAt"`
}
```

Comment: =P saw your comment and immediately started amending. +1 - pushing my changes to validate. Also, didin't know about the `dynamodbav:"prop"` nice

Comment: la Thanks! that was it =)

Comment: glad it helped :)